# Alterando uma sequencia aleatória de caracteres usando StringBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, string, random, stringbuilder

Tenho as seguintes variáveis:

```
String mascara = "12****3*59**100*";
String numero = "12345768"
```

Existe uma maneira de substituir os asteriscos da minha variável ***máscara*** pelos valores da minha variável ***numero***?

**Exemplo aplicado na variável *mascara*:**

12 **1234** 3 **5** 59 **76** 100 **8**

Estou utilizando .net framework 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já que você explicitamente mencionou um `StringBuilder`, aqui vai um exemplo:

```
        var mascara = "12****3*59**100*";
        var numero = "12345768".ToCharArray();
        var mascarr = mascara.Split('*');
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();

        for (var index = 0; index < mascarr.Length - 1; index++)
        {
            buffer.Append(mascarr[index] + numero[index]);
        }

        var result = buffer.ToString();
        // Resultado: 1212343559761008
```

Para cada asterisco presente na máscara, a terceira linha de código irá gerar um item no array `mascarr`. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O bloco seguinte é apenas um loop entre todos os membros do array, adicionando o número relativo ao cursor do loop e adicionando tudo ao seu objeto `StringBuilder`.

(EDIT: Como bem mencionado por @LuizVieira nos comentários, é interessante mencionar que o último membro do array deve ser ignorado - por não ter sido ele próprio delimitado por um asterisco. Por isso, o loop vai apenas até `mascarr.Length - 1`. O código original já possuía este valor estipulado, porém este post não explicava a razão.)

Comment: Ótima solução. Mas me parece que na verdade o array tem 1 item a mais do que o número de asteriscos (porque o "*" foi usado como delimitador na separação). É só uma questão de ser preciso na informação. :) P.S.: Aliás, sugestão de melhoria: esse fato poderia ser usado pra validar os dados antes de processar, porque se por acaso o número de caracteres em `numero` for menor do que o número de asteriscos em `mascara`, o seu laço vai gerar um erro ao tentar indexar `numero[index]`).

Comment: @LuizVieira você está correto em relação ao tamanho do array - por isso o laço `for` vai até `mascarr.Length - 1` ao invés de `mascarr.Length`: O último membro do array deve ser ignorado, por não ter sido ele mesmo delimitado por um asterisco. Quanto à validação, também concordo - mas achei preferível um trecho de código que lidasse apenas com os pontos principais da questão do OP. De qualquer maneira, agradeço os comentários!

Comment: Sim, eu não quis dizer que o código está errado (aliás, a sua solução é bastante inteligente na minha opinião). O meu comentário é mais no sentido de que a *menção no texto* praticamente diz que `Split` "gera um item para cada asterisco", e isso não é exatamente verdade. A minha preocupação é apenas que essa menção possa induzir um entendimento errado do comportamento do método pra quem estiver aprendendo. Sorry pela confusão - eu mencionei a constatação do número de itens ser `n+1` apenas pra emendar a sugestão de validação. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Sem estresse, na próxima eu pago o chopp. =)

Answer (score 1):

Você não vai precisar de um string builder para substituir um caractere por outro... dá para usar um array:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var str1 = "12****3*59**100*";
var str2 = "12345768";
var chars = str1.ToCharArray();
for (int it = 0; it < chars.Length; it++)
{
    if (chars[it] == '*')
        chars[it] = str2[rnd.Next(0, str2.Length)];
}
```

1. Primeiramente, eu converti a string contendo os asteriscos em um array usando `ToCharArray`.
2. Depois percorro o array substituindo os caracteres '*' um por um.
3. O caractere de substituição vem de outra string, numa posição aleatória, usando a classe `Random`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira bem concisa e legivel:

```
int numeroIndex = 0;
var array = mascara.Select(
    ch => ch == '*' ? numero[numeroIndex++] : ch)
                  .ToArray();

var result = new string(array);
```

Para cada character `ch` na string `mascara`, se o character for '*', substituimos `ch` pelo proximo caracter na string `numero`.

Answer (score 0):

(Eu nao sei C#, mas suponho que essa solucao (em C++) funcione, com as mudancas certas).

```
int posicao = 0; // qual dos numeros na sua string numero estamos
for (unsigned i = 0; i < mascara.size(); ++i) {
    if (mascara[i] == '*') {
        // Se temos um '*' na mascara, substituimos pelo numero
        // com indice posicao em numero
        mascara[i] = numero[posicao];
        ++posicao; // incrementamos posicao
    }
}
```